# Prove that $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for all $x>0$.

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $f:(0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable and that there exists a constant $\alpha$ belonging to $\Bbb R$ such that $x*f'(x)=\alpha*f(x)$ for all $x>0$ and $f(1)=1$. Prove that $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for all $x>0$.

I tried integrating both sides of the equation, but not sure how the $f(1)=1$ comes into play here.  Any hints in the correct direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is $*$?

Comment: * = Multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)x^{-\alpha}$. Differentiate. Conclude $g$ is constant over $\{x>0\}$. Find the constant using $f(1)=1$, then find what $f$ is.

Comment: g'(x)=f(x)*[-alpha*x^(-alpha-1)]+[x^(-alpha)]*f'(x) ???

Comment: @user113009 Take a common factor of $x^{-\alpha-1}$. Then use $x'f(x)=\alpha f(x)$.

Comment: But x*f ' (x)=alpha*f(x)

Comment: OK, I see how that gets me that g ' (x) = 0 an thus g is a constant.

Comment: Ah, I think I get the f(1)=1 to find the C.  Correct me if I am wrong but g(x)=C implies f(x)/x^alpha = C which implies that f(x)=C*x^alpha.  Then using f(1)=1 this implies that C=1, thus concluding that f(x)=x^alpha.

Comment: @user113009 Yep, that is it.

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction Pedro!

Comment: @user113009 Any time. =)